# Using the onLoad method to load images in React?

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to have my gallery images render in as they load.
Looking online, I have learned about the `onLoad` method.
This is what I have tried to utilise, the idea being that the `preloader.gif` would render until the image is loaded and simply replace the image src with the loaded image.

As it is now(below), the images seem to load in the same way they normally would if I didn't use the `onLoad` method so there is a moment where no image is being rendered at all before the images load in.

What am I doing wrong exactly?

I've stripped down the code to make the question easier to read.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import preloaderImage from '../../../img/site/preloader.gif';

class WorksPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  imageLoadHandler(image,e) {
    e.target.src = image;
  }


  render() {

    const listWork = this.props.array.map((item,index)=> {
      return(
        <li key={item.id}>
          <div>
            <img src={preloaderImage} onLoad={this.imageLoadHandler.bind(this,item.image)}/>
          </div>
        </li>
      )
    });

    return(
      <li>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {listWork}
          </ul>  
        </div>  
      </li>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = WorksPage;
```

Comment: So it always renders your test image?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. 
No, it renders the final image. Visiting the page, you don't see the test image at all, it instead appears as the though the page is empty until the final images load in. I know that the test image is rendering because if I `remove the e.target.src = image` code the `preloader` image loads.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Here is an explanation why `preloader` image isn't rendered:

1. `preloaderImage` loads
2. When it is loaded `imageLoadHandler` triggers and `src` attribute is changed to the main `image` src (so `preloaderImage` isn't rendered even it is now loaded)
3. Now the primary image loads
4. When it is loaded it is rendered

---

#### How you should do it properly:

1. If you write React app, you should do it React way:

   - Set your images to the component `state` in its `constructor` method. You need to do it because you are gonna change the way your images are rendered (in React you achieve render changes via changing either component's `props` or `state`, in your case it should be `state`). But notice that you should set `src` property for each image in the list to your `preloaderImage` (in example below I am using [`object destructuring`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) syntax).

     ```
     constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
         images: this.props.images.map(image => ({
           ...image,
           src: preloaderImage
         }))
       }
     }
     ```
   - Now in `render` method create the image list like this (note, you don't need `onLoad` handler here):

     ```
     const listWork = this.state.images.map(image => (
       <li key={image.id}>
         <div>
           <img src={image.src} />
         </div>
       </li>
     ));
     ```
2. In `componentWillMount` method start to load your primary images `src` dynamically using vanilla JS (you can read article about it [`here`](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript)). As they are loaded call `setState` method to update images `src` property:

   ```
   componentWillMount() {
     this.state.images.forEach((image, index) => {
       const {src} = this.props.images[index] // get image primary src
       const primaryImage = new Image() // create an image object programmatically
       primaryImage.onload = () => { // use arrow function here
         console.log(`image #${index + 1} is loaded!`)
         const images = [...this.state.images] // copy images array from state
         images[index].src = src // adjust loaded image src
         this.setState({
           images
         })
       }
       primaryImage.src = src // do it after you set onload handler
     })
   }
   ```

   After `setState` is called with changed `images` array React will automatically rerender your images with correct `src` path.

---

#### More elegant way with the use of CSS:

Instead of `<img />` tag you can use `<div />` tag with `background-image` css property. There you can simply set your fallback (preload) image:

```
background-image: url('path/to/primary-image'), url('path/to/preload-image');
```

You can set paths dynamically with `style` property (in your `render` method):

```
const listWork = this.props.images.map(image => {
  const imageStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${image.src}), url(${preloaderImage});`
  }
  return (
    <li key={image.id}>
      <div>
        <div style={imageStyle} />
      </div>
    </li>
  )
})
```

Just don't forget to set `height` and `width` to this `<div />`.

Comment: I am definitely going to give this method a shot. The css method might not work because I want the image gallery to be responsive. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps but you could set a CSS property for your image while it is loading (e.g. opacity or visibility set not to display the image) and then change that CSS property when the `onLoad` event is fired. You could use the same for your preloader image, but obviously in reverse mode.

You also should be able to set a fallback action if the image won't load, by calling the `onError` function, also in the image that you are loading.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is with `React.createElement` because **onload must be defined in the DOM** (`public/`) or by functional react (2022)

```
const listWork = this.props.array.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={item.id}>
      <div>
        {React.createElement("img", {
          onLoad: this.imageLoadHandler.bind(this, item.image),
          onError,
          alt: title,
          style: {
            position: "relative",
            border: src === "" ? "2px gray solid" : 0,
            height: Style && !isNaN(Style.width) ? "auto" : optionalheight,
            width: Style && !isNaN(Style.height) ? "auto" : optionalwidth
          },
          ref: this.props.fwd,
          src: preloaderImage
        })}
      </div>
    </li>
  );
});

...
export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <WorksPage fwd={ref.current["fwd"]} {...props} />);
};

return <WorksPage ref={current:{fwd:this.fwd}}/>
```